Unable to install azurite - getting warnings on deprecated modules
I'm trying to install azurite but I'm getting the warning below. As a result, I'm unable to use azurite for my work. I already tried npm cache clear --force but didn't resolve anything.
Here is the warning:
$ npm install -g azurite
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.


similar question

Looks azurite package needs to update it's dependencies. For example, looking at this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/azurite?activeTab=code,
azurite has uuid ^3.3.2 as dependency and same thing for "rimraf": "^3.0.2".
Edit: All you can do is to raise an issue on their official repository on GitHub (if there is not one already, I see they have 300+) github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues

are you able to advise on how do I do this? I'm quite new at this.

Well, all you can do is to raise an issue on their official repository on GitHub (if there is not one already, I see they have 300+) https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues.
